# Who can cast spells during combat in Spellfire?

Tags: untagged

My question is about the rules for [Spellfire, Master the Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellfire), which is a collectible card game that was discontinued in the 90s. There is a set of rules posted online [here](https://www.moddi.com/spellfire-rules/); however, it doesn't seem clear who can cast spells (and spell-like abilities) during combat (phase 4). Is it only the characters who are active in the current combat round who can cast spells, or can characters that are in the players pools use their spell-like abilities to assist a combat? For me, the confusion partly arises because some spells can be cast during phases 3 and 5 (outside combat), as long as a player has a character in their pool that can use those abilities.

For example, say I have a hero attacking an opposing player's realm and a wizard in my pool. Can the wizard cast spells into the combat to assist the hero? If my opponent casts a spell, can that wizard cast a dispel magic spell to cancel their spell?

Presumably, the rule will be the same for spells and other spell-like abilities (e.g. psionic powers, thief abilities).

Comment: I used the 'playing-cards' tag, as there isn't currently a tag for 'Spellfire'. There also doesn't seem to be a general tag for 'collectible card games'.

Answer (score 1):

During combat only champions participating can cast spells (that were attached to them before the combat began). spells are first cast by the attacker, then the defender.

The rules aren't written in the clearest manner, but spell casting during combat is clarified as part of the **Order of Activation** section:

> 1. RULE CARD
> 2. DUNGEON CARD
> 3. REALM POWER
> 4. HOLDING POWER
> 5. SPELLS, PSIONIC POWERS, AND OTHER CARDS **IN PLAY BEFORE BATTLE** (IN THE ORDER PLAYED)
> 6. POWERS THAT ACTIVATE “BEFORE COMBAT”
> 7. ATTACKING CHAMPION’S SPECIAL POWER AND ANY ATTACHED:
>    a.) Artifacts*
>    b.) Allies*
>    c.) Magical items*
>    d.) Blood abilities*
>    e.) Thief skills*
>    f.) Unarmed combat cards*
>    g.) Psionic power cards*
>    h.) **Spells***
> 8. DEFENDING CHAMPION’S SPECIAL POWER AND:
>    Attached cards (same order as attacker)
>
>    *Multiple same-type cards activate first by highest bonus modifier and then alphabetically (starting with the first letter of the card name). When determining bonus, use only the number in the card’s icon. In the case of same-name cards with no bonuses, lowest card number goes first.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct. Generally, spells (and allies) don't need to be attached to champions prior to combat to be used. Ones that are designated to be played in phase 3 *can* be, but there are phase 4 spells that are intended to be played during combat. From the Combat section: "Compare the total levels again. The losing player keeps playing cards one at a time until he is winning."

Comment: I don't see anything in that Order of Activation section that clearly states that only the champions active in the combat can cast spells. The spells could have been attached by being cast by a spellcaster in the player's pool.